# rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = port '7050' is already in use by service orderer_org1' (kc0if2dce5t7lzrl0crg4ttyz) as an ingress port

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

Im facing following error in docker swarm with multi hosts:

```
failed to create service fabric_orderer: Error response from daemon: rpc 
error: code = InvalidArgument desc = port '7050' is already in use by 
service 'hlf_orderer_orderer_org1' (kc0if2dce5t7lzrl0crg4ttyz) as an ingress port
ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
```

Please assist

Comment: You already have a container "hlf_orderer_orderer_org1" running on port 7050 and you are trying to run another container "fabric_orderer" on same port. If you don't want "hlf_orderer_orderer_org1", then just delete it or else change the listening port number for "fabric_orderer"

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding your orderer is already running

look for all the running containers :  `docker container ls`

if orderer is running, you can check the logs :  `docker logs -f <container name>`

Or if you want to remove the container : `docker kill <container name>` and then `docker rm <container name>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`docker ps`
find in PORTS to find  use port '7050'

then use `docker kill <container>` which use port '7050'.
.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by use this writeStyle:
ports:
- target: 8848
published: 8848
protocol: tcp
mode: host

refrence:https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).